# fetch data to Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

is it possible to add data to redux state this method:

```
const dispath = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${location.state}&apiKey=${apiKey}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setNewsAll(data)
        console.log(data)
        setLoadingNews(false)
        dispath(data.totalResults) // <= this line ! i know that it must be async 
      })
  }, [location])
```

i try another method, but it is possible somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add data from API to redux. What you can do is create some action that can handle storing the state in redux and can easily dispatch from your effect.

```js
const dispath = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${location.state}&apiKey=${apiKey}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setNewsAll(data)
        console.log(data)
        setLoadingNews(false)
        dispath(setData(data.totalResults)) // setData is an action that can set state inside redux
      })
  }, [location])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add data to the Redux state using the useDispatch hook.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addData } from './actions';

const dispath = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${location.state}&apiKey=${apiKey}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setNewsAll(data)
      console.log(data)
      setLoadingNews(false)
      dispath(addData(data.totalResults))
    })
}, [location])
```